# Manga where a 3000 year old god gets bored and pretends to be a teenage girl

Tags: story-identification, manga

I think it was set in Japan, it had crazy panels! I hope somebody knows what I’m talking about, I’m not very sure about the age of the god though. The art style is similar to what you could say… 3D kind of realistic human models with a manga color style and shader, if you think of an real life picture with a sketch filter and then with an anime face drawn on, that is the style

Not very sure about this one: it was probably published in 2020?

The god pretended to be a high school girl, I think it was actually set in modern japan. I was planning on reading it in early 2023 but never did it because I lost the title, however as far I can remember, there was a panel that had similar Japanese things of folklore or such, statues, something you would see from Dandadan I would say (fantasy stuff in modern times) and the girl (god) with a high school uniform and a boy with uniform as well following her.

Unfortunately as far I can remember is that I saw it in reddit in r/manga, no idea the rest, however I’m sure is that the boy and the girl (god) I mentioned are both protagonists

Comment: Was the story full colour or mostly black & white? Was it set in _modern_ Japan? In roughly which year did you read it? And was the god initially depicted as being male?

Comment: @LogicDictates Hi! yup, the story was in black and white, I don’t know anything aside of the fact that the god pretended to be a high schooler girl, I think it was actually was set in modern japan, I was planning on reading it in early 2023 but never did it because I lost the title, however as far I can remember, there was a panel that had similar Japanese things of folklore or such, statues, something you would see from Dandadan I would say (fantasy stuff in modern times) and the girl (god) with a high school uniform and a boy with uniform as well following her

Comment: *San Yan Xiao Tian Lu* is about a God that manifests as a teenage girl.

Comment: @Valorum hi, thank you but unfortunately that’s not the one, but it seems interesting, might check it out later :)

Comment: Do you remember when you first found it, or any other hint about the original year of publication? Any idea what the god does after reincarnates? Just tries to live a normal life? Engage in romance? Fights other gods/demons/monsters? Was the god the protagonist, or a secondary character? This can be hard to know, but any idea if this was aimed at boys/men (Shounen/Seinen) or girls/women (shoujo/Josei)?

Comment: @qazmlpok thank you for asking, I’ll add the extra details in a few minutes, unfortunately as far I can remember is that I saw it in reddit in r/manga, no idea the rest, however I’m sure is that the boy and the girl (god) I mentioned are both protagonists

Comment: @Giacomo1968 unfortunately both of them aren’t what I’m searching for, as far I can pinpoint, it was published in 2020?

Comment: Are you aware of any other manga with a similar 3d-based artstyle? I see 3d models used for background artwork all the time, but I can't recall ever seeing 3d modeled characters in manga, only in a small number of anime.

Comment: No, unfortunately not, but if you think of an in real life picture with a sketch filter and then with an anime face draw on later, that is the style

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This may be *[Sanzennenme no Kamitaiou](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/sanzennenme-no-kamitaiou)*.

> A 3000-year-old god decides she wants to quit being a god, so she becomes a high school girl.

The synopsis is a pretty clear match.

[image] [image]

I don't believe the characters are 3d models; I'm pretty sure they're just drawn.

[image]

I assume this is one of the "crazy panels". At least some of the items in the background here do appear to be 3d models.

Comment: thank you very much!! this is the one I was looking for!!!

Comment: Oh my god that panel. The perspective, the richness, wow...

Comment: holy schmoly, that's so many detail for one panel, and looking at the art style it seems like it pursues kinda realism. that's a nice art